# User must enter a value if a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following input field and a checkbox:-

```
<input id="ClientManagerApproval_e565da24-d454-4537-b902-771a37689e9d_MultiChoiceOption_0" type="checkbox">

<input type="text" value="" id="ProjectManHoursUsed_becead30-410d-42de-872e-c12ad4c322b2_$NumberField" title="Man Hours Used" size="11" class="ms-input" style="ime-mode : inactive">
```

now what i am trying to do inside jQuery, if that if the checkbox is checked then the user must enter a value inside the input field, i tried this but it did not work (the alert will never show!)

```
if ($("[id^=ProjectManHoursUsed_]").value === "" && $("[id^=ClientManagerApproval_]").is(':checked'))
    
    {
    
    alert("Please enter Man Hour Used before setting the stage to Closure approval");
    result = false;
    
    }
```

Comment: What about `$input[0].checked`?

Comment: When are you calling that if? I suppose you need some trigger. Like when the state of the checkbox changes or the user tries to click "submit"

Comment: @NullDev this script will run when the user submits the form

Comment: @evolutionxbox can you advice how i need to change my code ?

Comment: `$("[id^=ClientManagerApproval_]")` is `$input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery has its own function for getting values. Replace

```
$("[id^=ProjectManHoursUsed_]").value
```

by

```
$("[id^=ProjectManHoursUsed_]").val()
```

---

See here:

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){

    if ($("[id^=ProjectManHoursUsed_]").val() === "" && $("[id^=ClientManagerApproval_]").is(':checked')){
        alert("Please enter Man Hour Used before setting the stage to Closure approval");
        result = false;
    }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="ClientManagerApproval_e565da24-d454-4537-b902-771a37689e9d_MultiChoiceOption_0" type="checkbox">
<input type="text" value="" id="ProjectManHoursUsed_becead30-410d-42de-872e-c12ad4c322b2_$NumberField" title="Man Hours Used" size="11" class="ms-input" style="ime-mode : inactive">

<button>submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result you're looking by using the following code snippet without needing any jQuery at all:

```
if (document.querySelector('.chkbx').checked) { // I'd recommend using class instead of id, here chkbx if the class attr of the checkbox input -> class="chkbx"
  alert("Please enter Man Hour Used before setting the stage to Closure approval");
   result = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to check if value is empty when value is undefined. If you want to make sure if there's any value, you can use `!` operator. You should use `===` to make sure for empty string over null.

I just changed your code from `$("[id^=ProjectManHoursUsed_]").value === ""` to `!$("[id^=ProjectManHoursUsed_]").value` and it's working fine.

```js
function testMe() {
  let result = true
  
  if (!$("[id^=ProjectManHoursUsed_]").val() && $("[id^=ClientManagerApproval_]").is(':checked'))
  {
   alert("Please enter Man Hour Used before setting the stage to Closure approval");
   result = false;
  }
  return result
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form onSubmit="return testMe();">
  <input id="ClientManagerApproval_e565da24-d454-4537-b902-771a37689e9d_MultiChoiceOption_0" type="checkbox"/>
  <input type="text" value="" id="ProjectManHoursUsed_becead30-410d-42de-872e-c12ad4c322b2_$NumberField" title="Man Hours Used" size="11" class="ms-input" style="ime-mode : inactive"/>
  <input type='submit' value="Click"/>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: This still wont work since `.value` is not a valid JQuery property

Comment: Run the code Snippet, it's working. What are you saying?

Comment: oh yea does it? Have you tried entering text into the input field and then clicking submit? The alert still triggers when it clearly shouldn't. See [here](https://imgur.com/a/PEOTkYl).